# ios navigation bar translucency set to NO changes height of UICollectionView at bottom

Tags: ios, ios7, uicollectionview, translucency

I have a very simple controller. I have a view with a navigation bar with translucency set to NO and a child UICollectionView. The problem is my UICollectionView's height is being shortened at the bottom (scroll all the way down) when I set the translucency to NO. When I set it to YES, I have no problems, the entire row in my UICollectionView scrolled all the way to the bottom displays fine.

I tried using:

self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

in viewDidLoad, viewWillLayoutSubviews, and even viewDidLayoutSubviews but I still see the same problem.

The amount of height that's being clipped away at the bottom seems equal to the navbar height and maybe even the status bar height but I"m not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try putting constraints in your collection view? I would like to know what's your collection view's frame… you could try to print it out using debugger and inspect the frame to see if its separation with the bottom is 0.

Comment: Here's what I found: My main view's h = 504pt, w = 320pt. My collectionview's h = 568pt, w = 320pt. Seems like my main view gets shortened somehow.

Comment: One more thing. I noticed in loadView, where I allocate the main view self.view = ...., the h = 548pt and w = 320pt. Something is changing my main view's height.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The issue was I was setting my UICollectionView's frame in loadView after allocating my main view. The new bounds of the main view was only being calculated after loadView. I moved the setting of my UICollectionView's frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews and everything worked fine.